# Configuring IIS 7.0 + JBoss 8 Wildfly via mod_jk

Tags: iis, iis-7, jboss, mod-jk, wildfly

I'm trying to get my Win2K8 Server (Intel Xeon 64bit machine) working with IIS7 web server and the latest release of JBoss AS (8 Wildfly).

I followed many tuts on how to get that done and I ended up with:

```
C:\mod_jk
         \bin
             isapi_redirect.dll (x86_64 v.1.2.40 for iis)
             isapi_redirect.properties (all paths correctly in place)
         \log
         \conf
             uriworkermap.properties (containing simply /mycontext/*=myworker
             workers.properties (containing myworker's configuration on ajp port 8009)
```

I omitted jk details because I never reach the filter (isapi_redirect.log is never created). However, Wildfly is configured for ajp and listening to 8009 port.

In IIS 7.0 I added the isapi filter and set the right permissions to all, according to the official documentation and several tutorials.

I keep getting a

**HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter “C:\Tomcat\ISAPI\isapi_redirect.dll” failed**

when visiting www.myhost.com/mycontext/

Enabling 32 bit appPool makes the error change in a common 404 - not found.

Can you suggest me a checklist to follow to make the whole thing work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ARR.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

That avoids AJP by simply forwarding all traffic to JBoss 8080 port.